# why iOS app's screen size can change after I select "iOS 8.0 and Later" in Launch Image and new the image for that?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

At first, the app appears black margin on top and bottom in iPhone X and iPhone 11
I want to make the black margin disappear, so I try to select "Use Safe Area Layout Guides" in mainViewController.xib, and it doesn't work.

Then I try to change the view size or view anchor in viewdidLoad in mainViewController, and all of those moves don't work.
Finally, when I open images.xcassets and select Launch Image -> Show the Attributes inspector -> iOS 8.0 and Later -> iPhone -> Portrait. Then there are three block appears on the xcode, repectively iPhone Xs Max, iPhone XR, iPhone X/ iPhone Xs.
I fill those block with picture according to the resolution.
Magic! When I rebuild the app, the black margins are disappeared.
**But why!?**

I use xcode 11.3.1, and use simulatore of iPhone 11 Pro()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If apps do not include launch images for newer device screen sizes then iOS assumes that the app was written before those devices were released and reduces the usable screen area to that of the older devices as a backward-compatibility solution.

When you include all launch image sizes this backward compatibility is mode is deactivated.

However, you should adopt a launch storyboard, not launch images as this makes it easier to support all screen sizes and will be required by Apple from July.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Is there any reference of this rule? like Apple's document? I try to search  but get nothing about it..

Comment: See [this page](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/) under “all screen support”. The April 30 deadline has been extended to June 30 if I recall

Comment: sorry I didn't say it clearly.
I mean the rule that "apps do not include launch images for newer device screen sizes then iOS assumes that the app was written before those devices were released and reduces the usable screen area to that of the older devices as a backward-compatibility solution"

Comment: But it's seen that I must change static image to launch storyboard lol. Let me discuss with my supervisor first

Comment: Oh, sorry.  From memory, the letterboxing behaviour came in when the iPhone 5 was released, so more than 5 years ago. It is probably mentioned in WWDC sessions from around that time.